# How to get Yammer messages of particular group?

Tags: ionic-framework, yammer

I used

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json
```

but am getting all the messages of yammer.
But I am in need of getting messages only for 1 group.
There is no group paramter in above API to sort.

I am in need of search message/topic of particular group.
Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

This is the API you would need to call: 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/{{group_id}}.json

I don't see this specifically supported in the Yammer Developer Docs so make sure you understand that it might be removed or changed in the future:
https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits

You could also use the Data Export Api and that generates a csv of messages that you could filter on group ids.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to search by group using the API. What you can do though is to filter the JSON response by the group ID. For example, if your group ID is 12346, fetch the response then apply a custom filter in your code to get all messages that has "messages.group_id:12346".